# WhereIN data for calculations for displaying results

Tags: laravel

I am trying to work out the best practice to calculate Avg Attendance.

I would like to show this on the Member View (html part is no issue)

I have the following 3 databases

Members DB

```
|id|first|last|..........
|1 |.....................
|2 |.....................
```

Rolls DB

```
|id|roll_id|member_id|status|
|1 |1      |1        |P     |
|2 |1      |2        |V     |
|3 |2      |1        |A     |
|4 |2      |2        |C     |
```

Rollmappings DB

```
|id|roll_date |roll_year|
|1 |2019-03-01|2019     |
|2 |2019-03-02|2019     |
```

I have the following in my Member Model

```php
public function roll()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Roll');
}
```

I have the following in my Roll Model

```php
public function rollmapping()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Rollmapping', 'id','roll_id');
}
```

I would like to count all records which does not equal "A"
So in the code blocks above Member 1 will needs to show me 50% attendance, and member 2 will show me 100% attendance.

I would need to have something in place which will auto roll over when we move into 2020
I do Have Carbon Date installed with the app as well

---

I got stuck on the link on pulling the `year_roll` into the select for the Roll and to count I can use:

```
$rollyear = Rollmapping::lastest()->value('roll_year');
$totalweeks = DB::table('rollmappings')
    ->where('roll_year', '=', $rollyear)
    ->get()
    ->count();
```

But I am stuck on on pulling the correct records from the roll using the `roll_id` as I only want the `roll_id` which have a year date of the current year.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to show the query you've already tried?

Comment: I got stuck on the link on pulling the year_roll into the select for the Roll and to count  I can use "$rollyear = Rollmapping::lastest()->value('roll_year'); then use $totalweeks = DB::('rollmappings')->where('roll_year', '=', $rollyear)->get()->count(). But I am stuck on on pulling the correct records from the roll using the Roll_ID as I only want the roll_id which have a year date of the current year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you're question correctly then you should be able to get what you need using [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
$count = Roll::whereHas('rollmapping', function ($query) {
    $query->whereYear('roll_date', now()->year);
})->count();
```

If you would also like to exclude all the rolls where the status does not equal A then you would have something like:

```
$count = Roll::whereHas('rollmapping', function ($query) {
    $query->whereYear('roll_date', now()->year);
})
    ->where('status', '!=', 'A')
    ->count();
```